# Which is an easy way to setup a data science front-end using Docker containers?

Tags: docker, hadoop, hdfs, hue

I would like to setup a data science front-end testing environment using Docker containers.
The platform should provide a user-friendly interface and be capable to manage huge CSV files.
My first approach was using a Anaconda distribution in order to leverage the flexibility of Python and Jupyter Notebooks. Unfortunately, given the fact that my team is using mainly data science libraries with Python (e.g. Pandas) this solution is too slow when working with huge CSVs.
I considered moving to HDFS using a front-end like Hue in order to have the benefit of working on data using SQL prior to export it and make data science on it with other tools. However, this approach is too complex (need to setup Hadoop, and many other things in order to use Hue).
Moreover, as far as I know, no official container for Hadoop is provided. And from my understanding, the Hue Docker container does not provide HDFS.

Is there something already available as a container, which provides the following:

- Possibility to load (huge) files (e.g. CSV) in a web gui or via simple means (e.g .SFTP)
- Working on big data via web gui using SQL-like tools in order to create intermediate data/visualization
- Possibility to export data in CSV or other formats
- Integration with other data science tools would be beneficial

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hue requires you to enable WebHDFS on an existing Hadoop cluster to work with the file browser.

The default Docker image is configured to only access all services running on localhost, but you shouldn't install Hadoop within the Hue container.

I personally find the BigData Europe containers to be the most configurable. You'll need a namenode and datanode container.

Then, if your HDFS is performing user account checks, you need to configure one of the login methods in the Hue that'll passthrough your HDFS user name. I do not believe the defaults will do this.

Hue container can be configured by using a volume mount for a `hue.ini` config file

Comment: Thank you, your answer was really helpful. However, I still do find this solution too much complicated for a development/testing environment. I'm updating my question in order to add more details

Comment: You can use lots of tools to load CSV into just a SQL database. Hadoop is discouraged unless you have tens to hundreds of GB or TB worth of data. There's plenty of GUI tools to connect to SQL databases. Apache Superset, Dremio, or Tableau are good examples. If you want to move data between FTP and other sources, try using Streamsets or Apache Nifi (both have official Docker images)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. I did not know about Superset. Tableau would be fine, but unfortunately it is not completely free. My dashboards at the moment are on Kibana, and I'm happy with that. All the data is stored on Elasticsearch, and the "cleaning" process for the moment is done via Python scripts. Instead of using these Python scripts I'm interested in understanding if there is a web gui out there which can do basically a Tableau-like work. Exporting the data to Elasticsearch would be a plus.

Comment: I recently came across a tool called Knime that basically is a graphical editor for Spark pipelines. And Spark handles CSV and Elasticsearch connections fairly well last time I had used them.